# privat div box inside wordpress post - only visible to the post author?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, privacy

How can I make a div box with "id=private" that is inside a post only visible to the author of the post?

I made it for the admin, but I want the id to be visible only to the author of the post.

Example:

If the author is logged in, he should see the content with id=private.

but

if another user is logged in, he should not see the content with the id=private.

My solution for admin:

```css
/* hide role-specific div */
#privat {
  display: none;
}

body.logged-in.admin-bar #privat {
  /* Admin is logged in*/
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: You need a server-side solution to detect the author, and remove the box from the page altogether, if the requester is not the author. It's easy to override CSS with the DevTools.

Comment: You have asked the same question about an hour ago. Just be patient and wait for an answer instead of asking the same question multiple times.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I display a div box with ID only for the corresponding author of the wordpress page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67717262/how-can-i-display-a-div-box-with-id-only-for-the-corresponding-author-of-the-wor)

Answer (score 0):

This might help you- [With PHP MySQL]

```
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {

     <div id="private">Your content</div>

}
```

No need for the CSS code
For using this you will have to make login form with PHP MySql

Comment: I don't think that's directly related to WordPress or the specific post author that was requested.